# jsp update Query

Tags: html, jsp

Pls help me out...i just want to do edit operation using jsp..if i press edit button i just want to edit the current row data...how to set row data to the textbox...how to match the current row to  text box

```
Employeeupdate.jsp

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%
    try{
        String n=request.getParameter("employeeid");  
        String p=request.getParameter("employeegender");  
        String e=request.getParameter("employeename");  
        String c=request.getParameter("employeesalary");  
        String d=request.getParameter("employeePhoneno");  
        String q=request.getParameter("employeeaddress");  
        String r=request.getParameter("employeeCountry"); 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  // MySQL database connection
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee","root","root123");    
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("Update emplo set emp_id=? emp_gender=?,emp_name=?,emp_sal=?,emp_phoneno=?,emp_address=? emp_country =? where emp_id =+ emp_id");
        ps.setString(1,n);  
        ps.setString(2,p);  
        ps.setString(3,e);  
        ps.setString(4,c);  
        ps.setString(5,d);  
        ps.setString(6,q);  
        ps.setString(7,r);  
        int i=ps.executeUpdate();  
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();                        
        if(i>0)  
        out.print( " successfully Updated by: "+e);  


        }catch (Exception e2) {System.out.println(e2);}  

        out.close();  

%>
```

Employeeupdate.html

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="HotPink ">
    <form action="EmployeeUpdate.jsp" method="get">
        <center>

            <h1>
                <b><u>Employee Update form</u></b>
            </h1>

            <table border="2" bgcolor="Khaki " style="color: black">
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Employee Id:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="employeeid"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Gender:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="employeegender" value="male">Male<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="employeegender" value="female">Female</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><b>Employee Name:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="employeename"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Employee Salary:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="employeesalary"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Employee PhoneNo:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="employeePhoneno"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Employee Address</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="employeeaddress"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><b>Country:</b></td>
                    <td><select name="employeeCountry">
                            <option>Select</option>
                            <option>India</option>
                            <option>Austraila</option>
                            <option>SouthAfrica</option>
                            <option>England</option>
                            <option>Usa</option>
                            <option>UAE</option>
                            <option>Srilanka</option>
                            <option>Pakistan</option>
                            <option>other</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <center> <td><td><input type="submit" value="Update"></td></td></center>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean edit in place or what ?

Comment: s bro..values r already in the database..if i press edit button means all the data in the particular row should display as per the textbox...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your HTML file into the jsp  and then populate your text fields as the following

```
  <td><b>Employee Id:</b></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="employeeid" value=<%=request.getParameter("employeeid")%>></td> //etc
```

Note, however, that java expressions inside a jsp file (<%= %>) are considered bad practice but they are fine if it's just a simple page.

You really should create a servlet and move your business logic there (database access etc).